# IIS URL Rewrite: Add trailing slash in url only once

Tags: regex, iis

I have a rule in IIS to append a slash at the end (if there is no). It is working fine but in my case, I only need it for the first time. I have a reverse proxy on IIS to forward the request to another server. With this rule, it appends the slash all the time.

How I can modify the rule to append the slash only if there is not any after a keyword like 'myapp' so that it appends the slash if a URL is like http://myserver/myapp

```
 <rule name="AddTrailingSlashRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" />
            </rule>
```

I tried changing the regular expression in url="(.*myapp[^/])$" but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the [^/] means there is a character which is not the '/'. So your regex will not work well for the myapp.

The right regex is `.*myapp$`.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I wanted to add a trailing slash only if there is not already in my URL after myapp. This regex worked well for validation but it is still not appending the slash. Am I missing anything?